# Out of Memory When Drawing Custom Font Sprite

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, draw

I've been making a game from scratch with Visual Studio 2013 Express in C#.

Everything was going smoothly until I ran into an out of memory error when running this code:

```
 public static class ExtraGraphics
{

    static string[] chars = { " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "\'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "¬", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~" };
    static List<string> charList = chars.ToList<string>();

    public static void DrawFont(this Graphics g, Bitmap image, int width, int height, string str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            g.DrawImage(image.Clone(new Rectangle(new Point(charList.IndexOf(str.Substring(i)) * width, 0), new Size(width, height)), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare), new Point(i * width, 0)); //Line that errors.
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
ExtraGraphics.DrawFont(canvas, new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("Assets\\font.gif")), sliceWidth, sliceHeight, text);
```

What this is meant to do is grab a strip of characters from an image (the custom font) and then split it up and display different characters depending on the intput string but when the str parameter has more than one character I get that error.

This is the sprite I'm using [here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/25yw41v.jpg).

Comment: You must of had a copy paste error as `g.(image.Clone(new Rectangle ...` is not valid code. What function are you calling on `g`?

Comment: Why are you using a bunch of `string`s instead of `char`s?

Comment: Also this line may not be the problem, but just the straw that broke the camels back. If you do not properly dispose of your objects you get a OutOfMemoryException when you run out of GDI handles or you have too much unmanaged memory that has not been cleaned up after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that draws character glyphs from a font image.

It first prepares a Dictionary that will keep all glyph bitmaps for later reuse. The keys are the characters for each glyph.

There is also a method to properly dispose of the dictionary when you don't need it anymore or when you want to load a different font image file.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prepareFont(fontImageFileName);
}


Dictionary<char, Bitmap> theFont = new Dictionary<char, Bitmap>();

string fontImageFileName = @"D:\yourfontimage.png";
string fontCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

int fontCharsPerLine = 7;
int fontCharsLines = 5;
int fontCharPixelWidth = 63;
int fontCharPixelHeight = 87;



void prepareFont(string fontImageFile)
{
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, fontCharPixelWidth, fontCharPixelHeight );

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(fontImageFileName))
        for (int y = 0; y < fontCharsLines; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < fontCharsPerLine; x++)
        {
            if (x + y * fontCharsPerLine < fontCharacters.Length)
            {
               char c = fontCharacters[x + y * fontCharsPerLine];
               Bitmap glyph = new Bitmap(fontCharPixelWidth, fontCharPixelHeight);
               using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(glyph))
               {
                   G.DrawImage(bmp, destRect, fontCharPixelWidth * x, fontCharPixelHeight * y,
                        fontCharPixelWidth, fontCharPixelHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                   theFont.Add(c, glyph);
               }
            }
        }
}


void disposeFont()
{
    foreach (char c in theFont.Keys) theFont[c].Dispose();
    theFont.Clear();
}

void drawFontString(Graphics G, string text, Point location)
{
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (theFont.Keys.Contains(c))
        {
            G.DrawImage(theFont[c], new Point(location.X + offset, location.Y));
            offset += fontCharPixelWidth;
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = panel1.CreateGraphics())
    { drawFontString(G, textBox1.Text, Point.Empty); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks though I already found a way to make it work by making the function only draw a single character and then have another function run it as many times as their are characters in the string.

I'm not really sure if it's more efficient than your method but here's a link to it: http://pastebin.com/aYEw2ge7

Comment: Well, I don't have time to try your code, but it __looks__ as if you are still __leaking__ the `Bitmap newImage = image.Clone(..` IMO you should add a `newImage.Dispose();` after the `g.DrawImage(newImage..`

Comment: Alright, I've added that in and it seems to have improved performance quite a bit!

Comment: Not sure why it would improve performance but it may well be so, if you were on the brink of the next out-of-memory condition.. The main point is to stop GDI objects (ie bitmaps, pen, brushes, icons and fonts) from leaking. You may want to check these in the task manager!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using memory *every* time the `DrawFont` method is called. This is because you are creating a new `Bitmap` object every time which is continually using more memory. The easiest way to fix this is to change your draw font routine to create the new `Bitmap` object in a `using` statement.

```
using (var temp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("Assets\\font.gif"))) {
    ExtraGraphics.DrawFont(canvas, temp, sliceWidth, sliceHeight, text);
}
```

You may also have to take the same strategy with your clone in order to completely fix the memory leak. Best of luck!

**Note/Edit:** One important item mentioned in the comments is when possible you want to try to load the images once - possibly when your form loads or during your initialization. This has two positive effects. The first is that you won't have to worry about memory leaks as much and the second is that you will significantly speed up your rendering loop (loading an image from disk is slow).

One final thing to think about is to use a `Matrix` to draw the part of the image that you are looking for rather than trying to clone the pixels that you want to draw. You will also see a huge performance benefit from this as well.

Comment: Totally agree with this solution but the "better" way to fix it is load the bitmap once and keep it in memory somewhere and just keep referencing the same bitmap over and over in your code. Constantly needing to read from the persistent storage every screen redraw will greatly slow down the game.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree completely. There is too little code presented to necessarily provide that as a solution. Never the less, I will modify the answer to note this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying out your suggestion as we speak.

Comment: It seems the error still persists so I'm going to try using a matrix.